# Reading from file first element is quote windows phone 8

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, xmlreader

I am following a tutorial on windows phone 8 development, and there is an additional exercise to complete but I got stuck on some point. I am not very experienced with Silverlight and .Net so I hope this is not something trivial.

Basically, I will read a sample data file. The file is placed in the installed directory of the application. It is xaml formatted file and I will parse it with XmlReader. I know those things are not very good ( file operations in the installed direcotory etc. ) but I am doing this for exercise, therefore I didnt work on to make it a good application.

My procedure is as follows: 
First,  I read the file contents to a string and I pass the string to XmlReader. Here the problem starts. Read() function on xmlReader throws exception at line 1, column 1. So, I check the value of the "contents" string. In the Text Visualizer window everything seems normal, that is the contents string has what I put into input file. But when I evaluate the expression  contents.ElementAt(0) in a quickwatch window, the output is a " character and contents.ElementAt(1) is a < character, which I expect it to be the 0th element. And not oddly enough, when I remove the first element when reading the file ( as seen in the commented out contents.Remove(0,1) , I do not get the exception. However what I seen in Text Visualizer is the same. I could continue my exercise this way, but I  really would like to find out the cause of this strange behaviour. I thought it could be a bug in VS debugger, but in that case I shouldnt be getting the exceptions when running.

```
        string contents;
        try
        {
            StorageFolder localFolder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("SampleData");
            StorageFile file = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
            using (IRandomAccessStream textStream = await file.OpenReadAsync()) 
            {
                using (DataReader textReader = new DataReader(textStream))
                {
                    uint length = (uint)textStream.Size;
                    await textReader.LoadAsync(length);
                    contents = textReader.ReadString(length);
                    //contents = contents.Remove(0, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        catch 
        {
            contents = "TODO catch exception";
        }

        return contents;
```

xml parsing:

```
            string filePath = "SampleData.xaml";

        string contents = await FileHelper.ReadFile(filePath);

        // parse xaml string

        using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create ( new StringReader (contents) ) )
        {
            try
            {
                while (xmlReader.Read())
                {
                    string temp = xmlReader.ReadContentAsString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: How about using [Linq 2 Xml](https://www.google.com/?q=linq+2+xml) I find it easier to use.

Comment: yes, that would be a nice option, it is in my to learn list. Actually as I mentioned in the post, I could continue to my project by removing the first element from the string. However,  I would like to find the cause of this issue, why would there be an extra " in the input stream.